# How to isolate colour Green from the Picture.

Tags: matlab

The picture is:
[image]

How do I isolate the green chips? The result must be in black and white. It doesn't have to be perfect.

To isolate the blue ones I used:

> > I=imread('Picture.png');
> >     A=I(:,:,3);
> >     B=(A>230)
> >     figure imshow (B)

How do I isolate i)Green ii)Yellow

Comment: Can this question be asked in math SE?

Comment: Yes its a maths question with Matlab.

Comment: Is it possible to convert from RGB to HSV? That would make things much more robust, I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Colours are represented by their RGB values. I don't know much about Matlab, but I suppose you could simply search online for the RGB values of different shades of green and yellow and create a numerical range of colours that match as green or yellow.

There are softwares where you can upload your picture, click on a series of pixels and get an approx. range of RGB values for them.